# applying the Similar function in Gensim.Doc2Vec

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to get the doc2vec function to work in python 3.
I Have the following code:

```
tekstdata = [[ index, str(row["StatementOfTargetFiguresAndPoliciesForTheUnderrepresentedGender"])] for index, row in data.iterrows()]
def prep (x):
    low = x.lower()
    return word_tokenize(low)

def cleanMuch(data, clean):
    output = []
    for x, y in data:
        z = clean(y)
        output.append([str(x), z])
    return output

tekstdata = cleanMuch(tekstdata, prep)

def tagdocs(docs):
    output = []    
    for x,y in docs:
        output.append(gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(y, x))
    return output
    tekstdata = tagdocs(tekstdata)

    print(tekstdata[100])

vectorModel = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(tekstdata, size = 100, window = 4,min_count = 3, iter = 2)


ranks = []
second_ranks = []
for x, y in tekstdata:
 print (x)
 print (y)
 inferred_vector = vectorModel.infer_vector(y)
 sims = vectorModel.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=1001,   restrict_vocab = None)
rank = [docid for docid, sim in sims].index(y)
ranks.append(rank)
```

All works as far as I can understand until the rank function. 
The error I get is that there is no zero in my list e.g. the documents I am putting in does not have 10 in list:

```
  File "C:/Users/Niels Helsø/Documents/github/Speciale/Test/Data prep.py", line 59, in <module>
rank = [docid for docid, sim in sims].index(y)

ValueError: '10' is not in list
```

It seems to me that it is the similar function that does not work. 
the model trains on my data (1000 documents) and build a vocab which is tagged.
The documentation I mainly have used is this: 
[Gensim dokumentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)
[Torturial](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb)

I hope that some one can help. If any additional info is need please let me know. 
best
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting `ValueError: '10' is not in list`, you can rely on the fact that `'10'` is not in the list. So have you looked at the list, to see what is there, and if it matches what you expect?

It's not clear from your code excerpts that `tagdocs()` is ever called, and thus unclear what form `tekstdata` is in when provided to `Doc2Vec`. The intent is a bit convoluted, and there's nothing to display what the data appears as in its raw, original form.

But perhaps the `tags` you are supplying to `TaggedDocument` are not the required list-of-tags, but rather a simple string, which will be interpreted as a list-of-characters. As a result, even if you're supplying a `tags` of `'10'`, it will be seen as `['1', '0']` – and `len(vectorModel.doctags)` will be just 10 (for the 10 single-digit strings).

Separate comments on your setup:

- 1000 documents is pretty small for `Doc2Vec`, where most published results use tens-of-thousands to millions of documents
- an `iter` of 10-20 is more common in `Doc2Vec` work (and even larger values might be helpful with smaller datasets)
- `infer_vector()` often works better with non-default values in its optional parameters, especially a `steps` that's much larger (20-200) or a starting `alpha` that's more like the bulk-training default (`0.025`)